Problemas con la respuesta del CORS con Express
Tengo un backend hecho con express, el cual tiene el script server.js con lo siguiente:
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT;
const cors = require('cors');

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}))

app.use('/tasks', cors(), require('./routes/tasks.route.js'));

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server on! Listen on port ${port}`);
});


este backend corre en el puerto 3001, porque mi frontend está realizado como otro proyecto (proyecto hecho con Next.js) corriendo en el puerto 3000. En mi frontend tengo un hook para pedir consultas (solo GET por ahora) al backend de la siguiente manera:
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export function useFetch({ url }) {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [error, setError] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getData = () => {
      fetch(url)
        .then((response) => {
          if (response.ok) {
            console.log(response);
            response.json();
          }
        })
        .then((data) => setData(data))
        .catch((err) => setError(err))
        .finally(() => setIsLoading(false));
    };
    getData();
  }, [url]);

  return { data, error, isLoading };
}

sin embargo, aunque la salida por la consola del backend me devuelve lo que pido, cuando vengo a ver la respuesta por el frontend solo obtengo esto:
Response {type: 'cors', url: 'http://localhost:3001/tasks', redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}
body: ReadableStream
bodyUsed: true
headers: 
  [[Prototype]]: Headers
ok: true
redirected: false
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
type: "cors"
url: "http://localhost:3001/tasks"
[[Prototype]]: Response

no sé que me falta por hacer para obtener mi json con la respuesta del backend; o qué debería cambiar.

Tu problema es que no estas pasando la promesa que devuelve response.json() al siguiente then.
Cuando escribes response.json(), este devuelve una promesa que se resuelve con el resultado de pasar el cuerpo de la petición a JSON, esta promesa debe pasarse al siguiente then para obtener dicho resultado (para resolverse), en tu caso no estas devolviendo nada y entonces data contendrá el valor undefined.
Es fácil de arreglar, cuando la función que pasa a JSON tiene llaves (ya sea la forma de declarar funciones clásica, o con funciones flecha con llaves) debes retornar el valor:
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos')
  .then(response => {
    return response.json()
  })
  .then(response => setdata(response))
  .catch(err => console.log(err))

Con funciones flecha sin llaves, el valor puede retornarse implícitamente:
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => setdata(response))
      .catch(err => console.log(err))

ReadableStream en este caso representa un flujo de datos que aun no ha sido leído por completo.
